# Passing function as JSON data in angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 2.0.0 with Typescript and trying to build a dynamic menu system which works based on JSON array the component receives.

```
var menu = [
{id:"menu1", title: " Menu 1", action: "addUser()"},
{id:"menu2", title: " Menu 2", action: "addPhoto()"},
{id:"menu3", title: " Menu 3", action: "addEmail()"}
]
```

I would like to know the following

- how to set the click action on the menu dynamically?
- Do I use Renderer with ElementRef or do I use DynamicComponentLoader?
- How do I represent the 'action' click function as part of the JSON array above?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(click)="item.action"` **won't work.**

You should do something like that insteard:

`(click)="onClick(item)"`

Then handle the logic based on `item.action` value inside your

```
     onClick(item) { 
          switch (item.action){
            case 'addUser()' :
              this.addUser()
              break;
            case 'addPhoto()' :
              this.addPhoto()
              break;
            default : whatever();
          }
     }
```

Or antother option is:

Change your `menu` to by taknig out the `()` from your actions:

```
  var menu = [
    {id:"menu1", title: " Menu 1", action: "addUser"},
    {id:"menu2", title: " Menu 2", action: "addPhoto"},
    {id:"menu3", title: " Menu 3", action: "addEmail"}
  ]
```

Than in your template just do:
`(click)="item.action ? this[item.action].call(this) : 'return false;'"`

Or just:
`(click)="this[item.action].call(this)"` incase if your `item.action` is compulsory

Comment: Thanks. I like how you've given me a few different options. I like the last option best, which seems a bit elegant. Is this a standard way to do something like this dynamically?

Comment: @andthereitgoes I am doing second option which is using `.call(this)` in my current project. This one is much cleaner then the other one which requires you to build additional `switch` statement.

Comment: I am inclined to agree. i have selected that as the answer for now unless some other option or way comes to light - in which case I will update. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To bind to the click event dynamically, you do `(click)=""` Please see [**Event Binding**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding), but since those are technically strings it won't call a function you need a helper function to determine what function you want to call then it calls the function for you

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cfdDx7Lb0fFHTpRafEC6?p=preview) Demo

This should work, and the way you have action is fine

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div class="link" [id]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of menu"
        (click)="callFunction(item.action)">
          {{ item.title }}
      </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  menu: any;
  constructor() {
    this.menu = [
      {id:"menu1", title: "Add User", action: "addUser()"},
      {id:"menu2", title: "Add Photo", action: "addPhoto()"},
      {id:"menu3", title: "Add Email", action: "addEmail()"}
    ]
  }

  callFunction(func) {
    switch(func) {
      case "addUser()": 
        this.addUser()
        break;
      case "addPhoto()": 
        this.addPhoto()
        break;
      case "addEmail()": 
        this.addEmail()
        break;
      default:
        alert("Not found")
    }
  }

  addUser() {
    alert("Add User Called!");
  }
  addPhoto() {
    alert("Add Photo Called!");
  }
  addEmail() {
    alert("Add Email Called!");
  }
}
```

For more information on the [**Template Syntax**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

- [Property Binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding)
- [Attribute, Class, and Style Bindings](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings)
- [Event Binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding)

Comment: Thanks for this method. Is this a standard way to do something like this dynamically?